# Print string with null character in java

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, binary-data

I have string which contains null character ie `\0`. How can I print the whole string in java?

```
String s = new String("abc\u0000def");
System.out.println(s.length());

System.out.println(s);
```

Output on eclipse console:

```
7
abc
```

Length is that of complete string, but how can I print the whole string?

**UPDATE:** I am using

*Eclipse Helios Service Release 2*

*Java 1.6*

Comment: Works for me (Eclipse console), output is `7<nl>abc def` - on what system, and on which console, did you start the program?

Comment: It prints `abc def`. What else do you expect it to print? (There is no space actually between abc & def, its a null char there, but it prints though)

Comment: so you want `\u0000` in output?

Comment: btw, there's no good reason to write new String("abc\u0000def") in this context. "abc\u0000def" would suffice.

Comment: Do you want `abc def` as output or do you literally want `abc\u0000def`?

Comment: @Andreas I have updated my question, please have a look

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl I just want that all the printable chars are printed, and whatever is printed for unprintable chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Eclipse won't cooperate, I'd suggest replacing the null characters with spaces before printing:

```
System.out.println(s.replace('\u0000', ' '));
```

If you need to do this in a lot of places, here's a hack to filter them from System.out itself:

```
import java.io.*;

...

System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FilterOutputStream(
        new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out)) {
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        if (b == '\u0000') b = ' ';
        super.write(b);
    }
}));
```

Then you can call System.out methods normally, with all the data going through the filter.

Answer (score 3):

Converting the `String` to `char` array is an alternative. This works for me:

```
System.out.println(s.toCharArray());
```

Which outputs `abcdef` to the console (eclipse).

Answer (score 1):

the correct output of your code using Java 5 or higher is

```
public class TestMain
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String s = new String("abc\u0000def");
        System.out.println(s.length());
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

> 7
>   abc def